# Faith cannot move mountains but can create someone who can (Discworld)

Tags: story-identification, episode-identification, quotes, discworld, terry-pratchett

In one of the Discworld novels by Terry Pratchett he wrote something along the lines of:

> Faith cannot move mountains but can create someone who can

I think it is from "Reaper Man" but I can't verify it. Can you tell in which book this sentence appears, and what is the exact quote of it?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

The quote is indeed from *[Reaper Man](https://archive.org/details/reaperman0000prat)*, but concerns belief rather than faith. The exact quote is:

> Belief is one of the most powerful organic forces in the multiverse.
> It may not be able to move mountains, exactly. But it can create
> someone who can.